# Helm go sdk install chart from external location

Tags: go, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Im using the following code to install chart that is bounded in my source code (eg. in my `app/chart/chart1`  in my go bin app), Now I need to move the chart to **git repository** or to **artifactory**,

My question is how can I install the chart from outside my program?

This is the code I use which works for bundled chart

I use the `helm3` loader package which works when I have the chart bundled in my app

```
chart, err := loader.Load(“chart/chart1”)
```

https://pkg.go.dev/helm.sh/helm/v3@v3.5.4/pkg/chart/loader

Should I load it somehow with an http call or helm have some built in functionality  ? we need some **efficient  way** to handle it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this for installing `nginx` chart

```golang
    myChart, err := loader.Load("https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/nginx-8.8.4.tgz")
...
    install := action.NewInstall(m.actionConfig)
    install.ReleaseName = "my-release"
...
    myRelease, err := install.Run(myChart, myValues)
```

It would be similar to:

```
helm install my-release https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami/nginx-8.8.4.tgz
```

Comment: This does not work. (anymore?)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that helm during its upgrade/install commands checks first a couple of different locations which you can see [getting called here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/v3.5.4/cmd/helm/install.go#L185). The content of that function is [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/1b5edb69df3d3a08df77c9902dc17af864ff05d1/pkg/action/install.go#L627).
And then continues [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/v3.5.4/cmd/helm/install.go#L199) with `loader.Load`

Comment: Thanks, could you please provide code example how can I make it works?

Answer (score 2):

`loader.load` checks only for files and directories. If you want to use URL helm sdk provides `LocateChart` method in Install interface. Here is an example:

```golang
settings := cli.New()
actionConfig := new(action.Configuration)
if err := actionConfig.Init(settings.RESTClientGetter(), settings.Namespace(), os.Getenv("HELM_DRIVER"), log.Printf); err != nil {
        log.Printf("%+v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
        }

client := action.NewInstall(actionConfig)

chrt_path, err := client.LocateChart("https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases/download/helm-chart-4.0.6/ingress-nginx-4.0.6.tgz", settings); if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}

myChart, err := loader.Load(chrt_path); if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}
```

Then you can simple setup install options and call `client.Run` method.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because `LocateChart()` is required for URL based charts.